# Map Azure Resource Tags with Resource GUID in Invoice sheet

Tags: azure, billing

Need to Map Azure resource Tags configured in multiple subscription with Resource GUID in the Microsoft Partner portal invoice sheet. Kindly let me know whether is it possible with any API or via. powershell script?

Comment: Ca you post sample data? i.e. how the "Microsoft Partner portal invoice sheet" looks, and what you want to do?

Comment: Is the Subscriptions Azure Global subscriptions or Azure Plan subscriptions? There is one API but how you get the information depends on the type of subscription. You can find all information you need in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/partner-center-rest-api-reference

Comment: If its "MS-AZR-0145P" - Subscriptions then you can use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-all-monthly-usage-records-for-a-subscription and if its Azure Plan you can use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-a-customer-subscription-meter-usage-records